# Singleton struct. Can someone show me how to do this?

Tags: c++, singleton

Someone gave me example code for making a singleton struct. Now I've been trying to add to it (the POD member) and actually use it (first in main() then, leter, in other functions). It compliles with the lines I tried to add commmented out. Can someone please show me how to do what I'm trying to do with it?

Someone gave me example code for making a singleton struct. Now I've been trying to add to it (the POD member) and actually use it (first in main() then, leter, in other functions). It compliles with the lines I tried to add commmented out. Can someone please show me how to do what I'm trying to do with it?

```
//What - oh - what, does one have to do to get this sob to format the code correctly!

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAXNAME = 31;

struct Singleton {
private:

Singleton() {}
Singleton(const Singleton&); // Disabling copy-ctor
Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&);

static Singleton* instance;

public:

int DeptNum;
char Name[MAXNAME];
int Age;
int EmplID;  // key field

static Singleton* GetInstance() {
    if (!instance)
        instance = new Singleton();

    return instance;
}

};

Singleton* Singleton::instance = NULL;
//Singleton* TmpRec = Singleton* Singleton::instance;  <-   COMMENTED BECAUSE WRONG

int main(void) {

   //Access POD members and load them with data

   //TmpRec-> DeptNum = 30;  <- COMMENTED BECAUSE WRONG

   //Print out POD members

   //cout << "Value of DeptNum is: " << TmpRec->DeptNum << endl;  <- COMMENTED BECAUSE WRONG

   return 0;
}
```

PS: this thing is KILLING me on formatting code...

---

Edit:

The question ISN'T whether I should use a singleton or not. It ISN'T about whether singletons are good or bad in practice. It ISN'T about any previous question I asked about a singleton struct (struct being the operative word here - not class). It's ISN'T even about the difference between structs and classes.

I've paid a lot of dues to learn how I learn best. Yes, I study basics too (all the time). This question IS aimed getting a litttle code that ACTUALLY works (compiles without errors and does the couple simple things I need to see in action).

Downvoting me because you don't like my question? Well, I can't control that, It's people's prerogative I guess.

Those of you who would like to add something that's actually constructive ...  Thanks so very much.

Those of you who just act like ...  eh' hem! Skip you anyway...

Comment: Blocks of code are done by indenting the text by four spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: [Whyyyyyyyy?!](http://jalf.dk/singleton/)

Comment: -1 too much singleton. -1 too much `NULL`. -1 too much `new`. -1 too much pointer.

Comment: Your previous question had some answers showing singletons working without pointers and dynamic allocation. You seem to have gone for the worse option (singleton being bad per se, that is the worse of the worse :-) )

Comment: No. This is a separate question. Yes, the previous question got me a working singleton struct (struct, not class) but without the POD members I added and had nothing to do with how to access and manipulate the instance of the singletop -> which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is fine, the second part should be:

```
Singleton* TmpRec = NULL;

int main(void) {
    TmpRec = Singleton::GetInstance();
    TmpRec->DeptNum = 30;
    cout << "Value of DeptNum is: " << TmpRec->DeptNum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that GetInstance is called within main, and ::instance is never used.

As for fully working code, here's a version which uses references instead of pointers:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAXNAME = 31;

struct Singleton {
private:
    Singleton() {}
    Singleton(const Singleton&);
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&);

    static Singleton* instance;

public:
    int DeptNum;
    char Name[MAXNAME];
    int Age;
    int EmplID;

    static Singleton& GetInstance() {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return *instance;
    }
};
Singleton* Singleton::instance = NULL;

int main(void) {
    Singleton &TmpRec = Singleton::GetInstance( );
    TmpRec.DeptNum = 30;
    cout << "Value of DeptNum is: " << TmpRec.DeptNum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh and there's no need for TmpRec to be global; you can define it within main if you prefer (in fact, that would be the main reason for even having a singleton in the first place; any function you retrieve it from will give you the same instance. It's just a hidden global value)

Comment: ~/Desktop$ g++ -o CodePad.bin CodePad.cpp
CodePad.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
CodePad.cpp:36:4: error: ‘TmpRec’ was not declared in this scope

http://ideone.com/RcbbkV

Comment: http://ideone.com/dg19zw

Fixed line 31, had errors, commented out line 31 and added "Singleton*" to line 36. Tried otehr things before that also (still compiler error). What I'm trying to get is actual, compilable, working code that I can then disect and learn by deduction how the concepts work.

Comment: See http://codepad.org/7EGRiGb3 (fully-working code based on my answer) and/or http://codepad.org/ZSJ6DZj8 (fully working code taking my comment into account). If you're having trouble with this I suggest working through http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/, which is a good primer to C++

Comment: Upvoted because it's the best of the answers available but still wish I could get something that's correct and working. I appreciate the suggestion for studying the basics (and I do that already - alot). But I've had to pay some serious dues to learn how I learn best.

Comment: This is correct and working. See the codepad sources I posted (which both compile and run correctly). As noted by some others, singletons aren't the best idea in C++, but the way I've mentioned is absolutely the correct way to do them.

Comment: Or you can use it like this: http://codepad.org/tPgK9T7z (with references instead of pointers)

Comment: Much, much appreciated my friend. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The code is incorrect because you're using the private data member instance rather than the public member function GetInstance().

Comment: Can please someone 'show' me what the correct code would be? (including accessing members, loading data into members, printing that data back out from the members).

Comment: @Jake: The correct code would be the following: ... What, you don't see anything? Good, because the Singleton is an anti-pattern. It sucks, it's highly frowned upon and please just don't use it.